# Jquery mobile autocomplete remote data source

Tags: jquery-mobile

i am writing an application that has a jqm client side and a web api. i am required to have am input that does an auto complete using a remote data source(that is where the web api comes in).

when running the application i seem not to see the drop down list of the available options from the web api though when debuging i can see the hit on my service.

sample code below.
JQM.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Autocomplete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-  1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        var $ul = $( this ),
            $input = $( data.input ),
            value = $input.val(),
            html = "";
        $ul.html( "" );
        if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
            $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://myhost/api/manufacturer",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    term: $input.val()
                }
            })
            .then( function ( response ) {
                $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                    html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                });
                $ul.html( html );
                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
            });
        }
    });
});
    </script>

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js">   </script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="myPage">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="autocomplete">Manufacturer</label>
                <ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-insert="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Manufacturer Name" ></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Web API service

```
public class ManufacturerController : ApiController
   {
    List<Manufacturer> manufacturers=new List<Manufacturer>()
    {
        new Manufacturer(){Id = 1, Name = "Audi"},
        new Manufacturer(){Id = 2, Name = "BMW"},
        new Manufacturer(){Id = 3, Name = "Mazda"},
        new Manufacturer(){Id = 4, Name = "Nissan"},
        new Manufacturer(){Id = 5, Name = "Ford"},
        new Manufacturer(){Id = 6, Name = "Mitsubishi"},
        new Manufacturer(){Id = 7, Name = "Toyota"},
        new Manufacturer(){Id = 8, Name = "VolksWagen"},
        new Manufacturer(){Id = 9, Name = "Renault"},
    };


    public IEnumerable<Manufacturer> GetManufacturers()
    {
        return manufacturers;
    }

  }
```

any help will be appreciated.

hi all managed to use jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min and it seems to be working, am having only one problem i cant seem to see the actual values from the Web Api list.the client list is only filled with "undefined" values. See code below

Client Side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> Hyper Finance</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
            $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
            $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.hidePlaceholderMenuItems = false;
        });
    </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"> </script>
<script src="Scripts/jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
  <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="search">Your city: </label>
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Test">
        <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
        $("#mainpage").bind("pageshow", function (e) {
            $("#search").autocomplete({
                method: 'GET',
                target: $("#suggestions"),
                source: "http://myhost:38605/api/manufacturer",
                callback: function (e) {
                    var $a = $(e.currentTarget);
                    $("#search").val($a.data('autocomplete').value);
                    $("#search").autocomplete('clear');
                },
                link: 'target.html?term=',
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The web Api remains the same. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try loading your jQM script before your page script. Also, in the .then(function(response) add an alert(response); to see if you are getting the expected results from the web api.

Comment: @ ezanker. thanks for your reply but its not working. this is what i want archive a) to see a drop down as i type into the search input b) be able to select an option that will appear in the input box

Comment: hi all i have managed to use the jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min and it seems to be showing the drop down list when i type in the search box. The problem i'm facing right now is that instead of seeing the actual values from my web api the whole list is filled with "undefined" values see code below